# Any better way to convert timestamp (HH:mm:ss) to Seconds in Hive

Tags: sql, time, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I have one hive field of type string which has timestamp in following format:
HH:mm:ss
mm:ss
ss
I need to convert them as below:

```
Input: 
10:30:40
   30:40
      40
Output Expected:
    10:30:40 = (10*3600) + (30 * 60) + 40  = 37,840
       30:40 =             (30 * 60) + 40  =   1840
          40 =                         40  =     40
```

I tried doing something like this

```
case 
    when duration  like '%:%:%' then 
            split(duration, ':')[0] * 3600 + 
            split(duration, ':')[1] * 60 + 
            split(duration, ':')[2] 
        when duration  like  '%:%' then 
            split(duration, ':')[0] * 60 + 
            split(duration, ':')[1] 
        else 
            duration 
        end
```

This works but seems inefficient way. is there a better way to do the same when I have to process billions of records.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `duration`?

Comment: String : sorry forgot to mention in my original post!

Comment: Then your method looks fine to me.

Comment: can you rewrite the sql assuming few things? 1. replace like with this `LEN(duration) -LEN(REPLACE(duration,':')) ` =2 or 1. 2. is it possible to replace split using `substr`? For example if you know first  2 character will be there so you can use `SUBSTR(duration,1,2) * 3600` and so on. I can help on sql if you want to know more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expressions will not create much additional load when executed in hive. You can simplify query a bit using `unix_timestamp` function, but it will run not faster.

```
with input as(--use your table instead of this
select stack(3, '10:30:40',
                '30:40',
                '40') as duration
)

select duration, case when duration like '%:%:%' then unix_timestamp(duration,'HH:mm:ss') 
                      when duration like '%:%'   then unix_timestamp(duration,'mm:ss') 
                      else duration
                  end as result
 from input
```

Result:

```
duration    result
10:30:40    37840
30:40       1840
40          40
```

Or even simpler:

```
select duration, coalesce(unix_timestamp(duration,'HH:mm:ss'), unix_timestamp(duration,'mm:ss'), duration) as result
```

returns exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response. did minor change by subtracting 21600 (epoch of 1970-01-01).

with input as(--use your table instead of this
select stack(3, '10:30:40',
                '01:00',
                '40') as duration
)

select duration, case when duration like '%:%:%' then unix_timestamp(duration,'HH:mm:ss') - 21600
                      when duration like '%:%'   then unix_timestamp(duration,'mm:ss')  - 21600
                      else duration
                  end as result
 from input